# Which update of SharePoint online is the latest?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've checked our version of SharePoint Online through /_vti_pvt/service.cnf, and I get: 16.0.0.1208

How do I know which update is the latest?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you would like to know exactly. Because of "cloud first" SPO has always the latest update.

Comment: Okay, so 16.0.0.1208 should be the latest version?

Comment: Yes, it is, but it is only a version available to MS itself, not a public one. Official / public version numbers listed here: http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346

Comment: @pholpar You should post that as an answer

Comment: You can't just assume you always have the latest because you're using SP Online. Right now my SP Online site is running 16.0.0.3514...

Answer (score 0):

Because of "cloud first", SPO has always the latest update, however it is only a version available to MS itself, not a public one. Official / public version numbers of the product (available to customers on-premise) are listed [here](http://toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346).

Comment: This isn't exactly true, feature updates are rolled out in waves to various customers using SharePoint online at different dates. There are a subset of users that recieve updates first (those who have opted into "First Release"), and even when updates are ready for production they are rolled out at different times.

Comment: So it's almost impossible to know when my SPO is getting the latest features?

Comment: @RangeRover in some ways yes -- that is a possible downside to using a completely managed service like SharePoint Online. The best way I've found to handle this is to work within the SP product team guidelines to avoid implementing features that could be broken by future updates. A great deal of those guidelines can be found at the OfficeDev Patterns and Practices GitHub repo: https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP